# C++ create a function similar to while, if, or for

Tags: c++, function, lambda

Think about this code in C/C++:

```
bool cond = true;
while(cond){
    std::cout << "cond is currently true!";
}
```

Is it possible to create a function that can be called like this?

```
myFunction(some_parameters_here){
    //Code to execute, maybe use it for callbacks
    myOtherFunction();
    anotherFunction();
}
```

I know you can use function pointers and lambda functions, but I was wondering if you can. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do so, because how would while() exist?

Comment: `while` is not a function but a part of the language. You can't create a function with the same syntax, but you can do something similar using a lambda, as you said.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here. Do you mean a function that behaves like a `while`? Normally you'd do `while (myFunction(args))`. Newer versions of C++ have `lambda` but I'm not sure this warrants going down that road. It can make for very complex code.

Comment: You might be able to fake it with macros. Depends on what you want `myFunction` to do.

Comment: `goto`? (ducks)

Comment: @DavidLively OP is trying to define a new flow control statement with usage similar to `while` or `if`. I don't see how `goto` can be used to define a new type of  statement.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux With creative use of macros, and a `jmp` (aka, `goto`), you can create whatever you want. It's a pretty pointless exercise, I agree, and you certainly can't just randomly add new constructs to the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(condition) { expression }` is not a function but a control structure / a separate language construct; it executes `expression` again and again as long as `condition` evaluates to `true` (i.e. something `!= 0`).

an function definition of the form `void myFunction(int someParameter) { expression }`, in contrast, is executed only when it is called by another function.

Hope it helps a bit;

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answers the question, even though it does clear up that `while` is not a function. But apparently it does.

Answer (score 3):

*Caution: this solution comes without the guarantee that your code reviewer will like it.*

We can use a trick similar to the one Alexandrescu uses for his [`SCOPE_EXIT` macro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ) (awesome one-hour conference, this bit is at 18:00).

The gist of it: a clever macro and a dismembered lambda.

```
namespace myFunction_detail {
    struct Header {
        // Data from the construct's header
    };

    template <class F>
    void operator * (Header &&header, F &&body) {
        // Do something with the header and the body
    }
}

#define myPrefix_myFunction(a, b, c) \
    myFunction_detail::Header{a, b, c} * [&]
```

Using it as follows:

```
myPrefix_myFunction(foo, bar, baz) {

}; // Yes, we need the semicolon because the whole thing is a single statement :/
```

... reconstitutes a complete lambda after macro expansion, and lands into `myFunction_detail::operator*` with acess to `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and the body of the construct.